# Retrieving a huge amount of data using MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have a database consists of 7 tables and each table contains millions of records. I am trying to retrieve the data from different tables using aggregate functions and JOIN clause. I am using MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin to run queries.

The problem is I cannot retrieve the data even when I limit the number of records. However, when I indicate the IDs of the required records to retrieve it works fine. For example:

```
select avg(grade) 
from TableA 
inner join TableB on TableA.ID = TableB.ID limit 5;
```

If I used the above query, MySQL will stop working until losing the connection to the server.

```
select avg(grade) 
from TableA 
inner join TableB on TableA.ID = TableB.ID 
where TableA.ID = 1 OR TableA.ID = 2 .... to 5
```

In the last query, MySQL will return the required result.

I would like to optimise these queries if I can, rather than increasing the server timeout.

Comment: Please provide tables structure. Wrong table indexing may cause to slow query execution

Comment: Could you add an [explain plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html) for your failing query?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `TableB`??  (`on TableA.ID = TableA.ID`)

Comment: The provided information is unclear. You have to specify the nature of the data that you have. For instance, to ease the task for the reader, you have to specify the structure of the table and what sort of data do you have. However, it's hard to give an answer for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample queries:

1. Read all of one table.  Or less than 'all' if there is a useful `WHERE` clause`.  (Not in either of your cases.)
2. For each row in that table, reach for the matching row(s) in the next table.  This uses the `ON` clause and `WHERE` clause if relevant.  (You have `ON`, but neither query has a usable `WHERE`; see below.)
3. That gives you a big temp table.
4. Do any other filtering -- such as that `WHERE .. OR ..`.
5. Do the aggregation.
6. Sort the result.  Oh, there is no `ORDER BY`.
7. Deliver a few rows, based on `LIMIT`.

That is, most of the effort occurs *before* the `LIMIT`.  (There are cases where an `INDEX` can be effective even into the `LIMIT`, but not in your examples.)

Which table is `grade` in?  Does it really give you the correct answer?  Are the two table in a 1:1 relationship, or 1:many?  If 1:many, shouldn't you do the `AVG` against one of the tables, *then* do the `JOIN`?  Note:  this will speed things up.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I can help you further.